# Xml parsing with python functions and create tab-spaced relational data

Tags: python, xml, function, parsing

Trying to parse xml generated by squish and create relational data in tsv format to upload it to database. Xml looks like

```
<SquishReport version="2.2" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2">
<test name="ATF_Sandbox">
    <prolog time="2016-05-05T06:43:43+05:30"/>
    <test name="tst_MapView">
        <prolog time="2016-05-05T06:43:43+05:30"/>
        <message line="30" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:44:41+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.001]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="759" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\suite_common\squishFunctions.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:44:51+05:30">
                <description>Check: Current map mode is 'Overview' mode</description>
                <description type="DETAILED"></description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <verification line="2264" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\suite_common\squishFunctions.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:44:52+05:30">
                <description>Teststep: CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.001 (Screenshot in "D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_46.png")</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">Screen shot captured: #REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: &lt;ccp is pointing north up></description>
                <description type="file">D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_46.png</description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="48" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:44:52+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.002]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="2264" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\suite_common\squishFunctions.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:44:52+05:30">
                <description>Teststep: CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.002 (Screenshot in "D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_47.png")</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">Screen shot captured: #REMARK WORKAROUND FOR : &lt;resolution of the screen is 400x240> &lt;Verifying width and height of the HomeScreen></description>
                <description type="file">D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_47.png</description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <verification line="61" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:44:52+05:30">
                <description>Comparison</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">'400' and '400' are equal</description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="71" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:44:52+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.003]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="2264" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\suite_common\squishFunctions.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:44:53+05:30">
                <description>Teststep: CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.003 (Screenshot in "D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_48.png")</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">Screen shot captured: #REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: &lt;Map is centered at center of map.></description>
                <description type="file">D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_48.png</description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="356" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.RDM.003]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="365" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[#REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: <Route preview is played at 300% of normal road speed>]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="370" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.RDM.004]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="379" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[#REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: <Route Preview starts playing from the beginning and keeps looping until the Route Preview is stopped>]]></description>
        </message>
        <message line="384" type="LOG" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\ATF_Sandbox\tst_MapView\test.py" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
            <description><![CDATA[CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.RDM.005]]></description>
        </message>
        <verification line="102" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\suite_common\squishFunctions.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
                <description>Comparison</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">'True' and 'True' are equal</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">Check if existence of widget ':HomeView.btnToggleMap_CMapTogglePushButton' equals True</description>
            </result>
        </verification>
        <verification line="102" type="" name="" file="D:\TestSlave5\workspace\TestSlave5 SyncCode\SquishTests\suite_common\squishFunctions.py">
            <result type="PASS" time="2016-05-05T06:48:22+05:30">
                <description>Comparison</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">'True' and 'True' are equal</description>
                <description type="DETAILED">Check if existence of widget ':HomeView.btnZoomIn_QPushButton' equals True</description>
            </result>
        </verification>
```

I am trying to achieve data in a relational format, which looks like -

```
CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.001  PASS    Check: Current map mode is 'Overview' mode  None    None
CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.001  PASS    Teststep: CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.001 (Screenshot in "D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_46.png")   Screen shot captured: #REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: <ccp is pointing north up>     MANUAL
CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.002  PASS    Teststep: CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.MPV.002 (Screenshot in "D:/TestSlave5/workspace/TestSlave5 SyncCode/SquishTests/ATF_Sandbox/tst_MapView\failedImages\failed_47.png")   Screen shot captured: #REMARK WORKAROUND FOR : <resolution of the screen is 400x240> <Verifying width and height of the HomeScreen>     None
CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.RDM.003  PASS    #REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: <Route preview is played at 300% of normal road speed>   None 
CS.VPR.MAP.VSL.RDM.004  PASS    #REMARK MANUAL VERIFICATION REQUIRED STEP: <Route Preview starts playing from the beginning and keeps looping until the Route Preview is stopped>   None
```

I am able to achieve that with the script below -

```
for test in root.getchildren():
for test2 in test.getchildren():
    for message in test2.getchildren():
        if message.tag == "{http://www.froglogic.com/XML2}message":
            messageText1 = message[0].text
            if re.match(testStepPattern, messageText1):
                testStepID = messageText1
            elif messageText1.startswith('#REMARK MANUAL'):
                remarkTag = message[0].text
                print testStepID, '\t', 'PASS', '\t', remarkTag, '\t', "None", '\t', "NOT AUTOMATED"
        elif message.tag == "{http://www.froglogic.com/XML2}verification":
            resultAttrib = message[0].attrib.get('type')
            resultDetails = message[0][0].text
            resultDetailsMore = message[0][1].text
            if "REMARK MANUAL" in str(resultDetailsMore):
                print testStepID, '\t', resultAttrib, '\t', resultDetails, '\t', resultDetailsMore, '\t', "MANUAL"
            else:
                print testStepID, '\t', resultAttrib, '\t', resultDetails, '\t', resultDetailsMore, '\t', "None"
```

But when trying to split this script into functions it's throwing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "parser.py", line 85, in <module>
   ParseXmlResults()
File "parser.py", line 56, in ParseXmlResults
testStepID, remarkTag = CheckAndGetMessageTagValues(message)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Below is the split code -

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\M1032828\Desktop\result_MapView.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
testSetTree = root[0][1]

testStepPattern = re.compile(r"\b([A-Z]{2,4}\.){4,5}[\d]{2,}\b")
testStepID = ""
tagDetails = ""


def ParseXmlResults_ESR():
    global testStepID
    for test in root.getchildren():
        print test
        for test2 in test.getchildren():
            print "--------------------------------->", test2
            for message in test2.getchildren():
                print '***********************>', message
                if message.tag == "{http://www.froglogic.com/XML2}message":
                    messageText1 = message[0].text
                    print messageText1
                    testStepID, remarkTag = CheckAndGetMessageTagValues(message)
                    print testStepID, remarkTag
                elif message.tag == "{http://www.froglogic.com/XML2}verification":
                    resultAttrib, resultDetails, resultDetailsMore = CheckAndGetVerificationTagDetails(message)
                    print resultAttrib, resultDetails, resultDetailsMore

def CheckAndGetMessageTagValues(element):
    global testStepID
    global tagDetails
    if re.match(testStepPattern, element[0].text):
        testStepID = element[0].text
        tagDetails = False
        remarkTag = ""
        return testStepID, remarkTag
    elif element[0].text.startswith('#REMARK MANUAL'):
        tagDetails = True
        remarkTag = element[0].text
        return testStepID, remarkTag


def CheckAndGetVerificationTagDetails(element):
    resultAttrib = element[0].attrib.get('type')
    resultDetails = element[0][0].text
    resultDetailsMore = element[0][1].text
    return resultAttrib, resultDetails, resultDetailsMore

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ParseXmlResults()
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: post full stack trace

Comment: added complete stack trace in the question

Comment: what's parser.py is it from the library or is it your code?

Comment: its just my code, the file where i have the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your getting this error is that there was a case when `CheckAndGetMessageTagValues` returned nothing, because neither of your tests: `re.match(testStepPattern, element[0].text)` nor `element[0].text.startswith('#REMARK MANUAL')` returned True, so it didn't run any of the `if` clauses.

What you should do is whether ensure one of these tests will always return True, or much better, add an else clause that would return default values (or maybe even better raise an exception, if the case is unexpected) when no one of the other conditions have been met.

```
def CheckAndGetMessageTagValues(element):
    global testStepID
    global tagDetails
    if re.match(testStepPattern, element[0].text):
        testStepID = element[0].text
        tagDetails = False
        remarkTag = ""
        return testStepID, remarkTag
    elif element[0].text.startswith('#REMARK MANUAL'):
        tagDetails = True
        remarkTag = element[0].text
        return testStepID, remarkTag
    else:
        return "defaultID", "noTagFound"
        # or raise an Exception?
```